# Configuration of a nested router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

There have been several questions regarding setting up wireless [access points](https://serverfault.com/questions/41572/adding-a-second-wireless-router-to-my-network) or [bridges](https://serverfault.com/questions/154176/how-to-properly-nest-a-wireless-router-behind-a-wired-router), but none that I can find which plainly describe how to set up a "nested network" in a residential setting.

I believe what I am attempting to do is create a "second TCP/IP subnet and routing between it and [my] existing LAN subnet," as another user mentioned in an answer to a related question.

**What type of hardware (cabling) and software (router properties) configuration would be necessary to create a "nested" wireless network, within the framework of a preexisting LAN?**

The current architecture:

[image: The current architecture]

The desired architecture:

[image: The desired architecture]

Answer (score 0):

That varies a little bit on what you are trying to accomplish with the nested network so let me ask...

- Which direction to you want devices to talk: B->A, A->B or A<->B?

I'm going to assume you meant; two networks: devices separated from each other but all able to talk to the internet.

In that case you would Plug the WAN on Router B into the switch on Router A just like in your diagram. Router B would then pull an IP address from Router A and all of it's clients would be NATed behind it which we commonly reffer to as Double NAT. 
I hops that helps.